# How can we simplify this switch expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Here is a switch function:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int level = 5;

    var indicator = level switch
    {
        1 => "C",
        2 => "R",
        3 => "R",
        5 => "R",
        6 => "R",
        _ => "D"
    };

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here all the 2,3,5,6 will return the same result "R", I try to add the key word "**or**", but there will be a Compile Error. Is there a way to simplify it? thanks.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int level = 5;

    var indicator = level switch
    {
        1 => "C",
        2 or 3 or 5 or 6 => "R",
        _ => "D"
    };

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: That won't work - 4 should be "D".  The code with `or` compiles and runs fine for me - are you compiling with C# 9?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version - specify `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`

Comment: My project is c# 8.0...